# Can't bind to 'ngModule' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. in angular 2 asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, asp.net-core

Package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

This is the app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginComponent } from "./Components/login.Component";


    @NgModule({
        imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
        declarations: [LoginComponent],
        bootstrap: [LoginComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

I have import the **FormsModule** in the app.module but still I am facing the issue.

This is the login.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'login-app',
    templateUrl: 'Home/partialLogin'
})
export class LoginComponent {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    constructor() {
        this.email = "erere@ada.com";
        this.password = "test anand";

    }

    login(event) {
        console.log(this.email);
        event.preventDefault();

    }

}
```

login.cshtml

```
 <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModule)] ="email" placeholder="username or email">
                    </div>
```

I have google it for the solution. Everywhere they have mention to import formModule which I have already added But still facing the issue.

Please can anyone solve this issue.

Comment: It should be `ngModel` not `ngModule`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it should be **ngModel** which **contains the value of the input field**

Where as **ngModule** is unlike a module in angularjs which is **used to organize an application** into blocks of functionality.

Answer (score 6):

It should be `ngModel` not `ngModule`. Read more at [NgModel documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="username or email">
```

Comment: Damn that typo, wasted few hours of mine

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" placeholder="username or email">
```

you can try `[ngModel]` alone too this is called property binding but when you use `[(ngModel)]` this is two way data binding

Where as `@NgModule` is an annotation of Angular2 which allows us to fetch bundle of code/components.

Comment: glad to hear :)